# postgres users can login with any or no password

Tags: linux, postgresql

So I set up a user called 'paperwork' with a database of the same name

```
postgres=# create role paperwork;
postgres=# create database paperwork;
postgres=# grant all privileges on database paperwork to paperwork;
postgres=# ALTER ROLE paperwork WITH LOGIN;
postgres=# ALTER ROLE paperwork WITH PASSWORD 'paperwork';
```

But it still lets me log in as paperwork without a password

```
[###@EMOO modules]$ psql --username=paperwork --host=localhost
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

paperwork=> \q
```

and when I force it to use a password, it accepts any password including blank password:

```
[###@EMOO modules]$ psql --username=paperwork --host=localhost --password
Password for user paperwork: 
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.
```

When I open up pgadmin3 and click on the "paperwork" user it seems to have an encrypted password.

```
-- Role: paperwork

-- DROP ROLE paperwork;

CREATE ROLE paperwork LOGIN
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md585ff97314dbeb9953b989fd363a8e96f'
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
```

Also, when I open up pgadmin3 it asks me for the postgres password, but again will accept anything for the postgres password. (and I remember setting the postgres password when I installed postgres) How do I make it so you need the right password to login? Or is there some context here that I am missing entirely? . . . like passwords are only needed for remote logins or some weirdness. Thanks.

EDIT: I didn't have a /usr/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf (EDIT: actually I did I just couldn't find it because I wasn't using sudo on the "locate" command)
I created one from the sample file: /usr/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample

Got this idea from here: http://blog.mattsch.com/2012/05/19/postgresql-accepts-any-or-no-password-when-connecting/
I tried making it have md5 authentication but I still have the same problem. What I tried is below from the file /usr/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf

```
@authcomment@

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

@remove-line-for-nolocal@# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   all             all                                     @authmethodlocal@
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5 
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.

@remove-line-for-nolocal@#local   replication     @default_username@ @authmethodlocal@
#host    replication     @default_username@        127.0.0.1/32 @authmethodhost@
#host    replication     @default_username@        ::1/128 @authmethodhost@
```

I then restarted postgresql but still have the same problem.

EDIT: Thanks [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto). that "show config_file" command (after logging in with pgsql)  put me on the right track. It didn't occure to me that "locate pg_hba.conf" run from my linux user's command line didn't have permission to find the actual config file in the postgres directory: /var/lib/postgres/data/ The user "paperwork" now gets rejected with the wrong password after I changed "trust" to "md5" in /var/lib/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf on these lines to make it:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5 
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Will probably mark solved in a bit just want to test a couple things.

Comment: In the `psql` execute `show config_file;` to find where your configs is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: oh sorry, what should I do? do I leave this here? or should I delete it and repost on a database stack exchange?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TLDR for my original post:

1. Make sure you have set the postgres password to something you know:

   ```
   [###@EMOO ~]$ psql -U postgres 
   psql (9.6.3)
   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres password';
   ```
2. Find your `pg_hba.conf`:

   ```
   sudo updatedb
   sudo locate pg_hba.conf
   ```
3. Replace "trust" with "md5" in your `pg_hba.conf`:
4. Restart PostgreSQL:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart postgresql
   ```
5. Log in as `postgres` and change whatever user passwords you need. Users will now be rejected if they don't provide the right password.

   ```
   psql -U postgres
   ```